# grep for contents after pattern for word character and comma

Tags: linux, shell, grep

```
echo  "this is a test:foo,bar,baz']" | grep -o -E "test:.*" | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'
foo,bar,baz']
```

I get `']` printed at the end, how to print only the word characters and common, nothing else, in this case I need to extract only `foo,bar,baz`

Comment: Do you have to use grep? You could probably replace the grep/awk with sed. echo  "this is a test:foo,bar,baz']" | sed "s/.*test:\(.*\)']$/\1/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `awk` for this:

```
echo "this is a test:foo,bar,baz']" | awk -F 'test:' '{sub(/[^,[:alnum:]].*/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

```
foo,bar,baz
```

Or, you can use a single `sed`:

```
echo  "this is a test:foo,bar,baz']" | sed 's/.*test://; s/[^,[:alnum:]].*//'
```

```
foo,bar,baz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "this is a test:foo,bar,baz']"| awk -F: '{sub(/baz../,"baz"); print $2}'
```

outputs

> foo,bar,baz

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu **grep** pearl regex

```
$ echo  "this is a test:foo,bar,baz']" | grep -oP "(?<=test:)(\w,*)+"
foo,bar,baz
```